# Email verify in sail.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to make a portal for filling up a form for which an applicant needs to create an account before filling out the form. The only issue is how can I stop from spamming the applicant creating account with fake mail. Is it possible to verify email in sail. I have done this in express using node mailer.

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer= require('nodemailer');
    var app = express();

    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "email",
            pass: "pass"
        }
    });
    var rand, mailOptions, host, link;

/*---SMTP OVER---*/

/*--Routing Started--*/
    app.get('/', function(req , res) {
        res.sendfile('index.html');
    });

    app.get('/send', function(req , res) {
        rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 54);
        host= req.get(host);
        link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/verify?id="+rand;
        mailOptions={
            to : req.query.to,
            subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
            html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href="+link+">Click here to verify</a>"
        }
        console.log(mailOptions);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                res.end("error");
            }else{
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                res.end("sent");
            }
        });
    });

app.get('/verify',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.protocol+":/"+req.get('host'));
    if((req.protocol+"://"+req.get('host'))==("http://"+host))
    {
        console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");
        if(req.query.id==rand)
        {
            console.log("email is verified");
            res.end("<h1>Email "+mailOptions.to+" is been Successfully verified");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("email is not verified");
            res.end("<h1>Bad Request</h1>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        res.end("<h1>Request is from unknown source");
    }
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/

app.listen(9999,function(){
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: Please don't post a link, if you can help me out with an example or something much better which explain my query.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use nodemailer in sails pretty much the same, just change the `app.get`s into corresponding controller actions.

MailController.js:

```
module.exports = {

    sendVerificationMail: function(req, res) {
        // your app.get('/send') code
    },

    verifyEmail: function(req, res) {
        // your app.get('/verify') code
    }

}
```

As a side note, your verifying logic kinda breaks when another user tries to register before the first one has completed his registration:

1. First user requests for email verification, `rand = 34` for example
2. Second user requests for email verification, `rand = 58`
3. First user tries to verify his email with `id=34`, verification fails since `34 !== 58`

Comment: Thanks for this great share, can you please help me out for some verification tip so that it will be possible to make this more robust.